# Exception Value: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json, django, request, postman

I am using postman to test if my django app call is working as expected but it is not.

I get the following error:

```
ValueError at /mobile/emulate_create&lt;/title&gt;
```

`Exception Value: No JSON object could be decoded`

I have the following code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def emulate_create(request):
    args = json.loads(request.body, object_hook=utils._datetime_decoder)
    resourceId, count, hours = args['resourceId'], args['count'], args['hours']
    now = datetime.now()
    remainder = now.minute % 15
    timeFrom = now + timedelta(minutes=remainder)
    timeTo = timeFrom + timedelta(hours=hours)

    reservation = ReservationProspect(byUser=request.user, forUser=request.user, resource=get_object_or_404(Resource, uuid=resourceId), modality=get_object_or_404(Modality, name="online"), timeFrom=timeFrom, timeTo=timeTo, count=count)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps[reservation.toDict()])
```

Does anyone see what might be happening here?

Comment: The string in `request.body` is not valid JSON.

Comment: How can I debug this? Not sure why it would not be.

Comment: To be clear, this is an issue with something outside of the code in your question. Try printing/logging `request.body` somewhere, and see what's in it.

Comment: I have been trying to but unable to do that :/

Comment: Try to find where the issue is, and ask a new question about it :). Feel free to post the link to the question as a comment here so I and others can easily find it.

Comment: How is the function called? what is `request` ?

Comment: Also there is a syntax error here: `json.dumps[reservation.toDict()]`

Comment: The code was never getting that far.